# Create an account in SQL Server through port using SMO

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, smo

I use SMO to create an account in SQL Server

```
var serverName = "192.168.1.50,1433" ;
Server svr = new Server(serverName);

var db = svr.Databases[databaseName];

if (db != null)
{
    // You probably want to create a login and add as a user to your database
    Login login = new Login(svr, loginName);
    login.DefaultDatabase = "uad"; // Logins typically have master as default database
    login.LoginType = LoginType.SqlLogin;
    login.Create(textBox7.Text, LoginCreateOptions.None); // Enter a suitable password
    login.Enable();
}
```

and I get the error:

> Failed to connect to server 192.168.1.50,1433

It's ridiculous, on the server I created an account successfully but on the client this errors happens and on the client, I have to connect to 192.168.1.50 port 1433 successfully, I can 'select' and 'delete' data in the table on the client. This shows that the connection between client and server completely correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create logins remotely to prevent hacking